# ExpoPushTicket does not contain the corresponding PushToken in case of error, how to know which pushToken is causing error to remove it from database

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, push-notification, expo

I am trying to send push notifications to more than one users of my app (pretty common to send more than one users. e.g notifying all users of a new feature).

When sending notifications, `ExpoPushTicket` array contains errors e.g. `DeviceNotRegistered` and I want to remove these errored `pushToken`s from my database as it indicates that the user have uninstalled the app.

But the problem is that I am not able to distinguish between working and non working tokens as in the request, there are more than 1 tokens and in response there are more than 1 `ExpoPushTicket` Objects.

How I can correctly map and know which push tokens are producing the `DeviceNotRegistered` Error?

Here is a sample code and a sample response.

```
import { Expo, ExpoPushMessage, ExpoPushTicket } from "expo-server-sdk";

const sendNotifications = async (): Promise<ExpoPushTicket[]> => {
  const expo = new Expo();
  // 100 push tokens for example.
  const notifications: ExpoPushMessage[] = [
    {
      to: '<EXPO_PUSHTOKEN1>',
      title: 'New Feature',
      body: 'We have a fantastic new feature, you might be interested to checkout.',
    },
    {
      to: '<EXPO_PUSHTOKEN2>',
      title: 'New Feature',
      body: 'We have a fantastic new feature, you might be interested to checkout.',
    }
  ];
  const filteredNotifications = notifications.filter((noti) => Expo.isExpoPushToken(noti.to));
  
  const chunks = expo.chunkPushNotifications(filteredNotifications);
  const promises = [];
  chunks.forEach((chunk) => {
    promises.push(expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync(chunk));
  });
  
  const chunkTickets = await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log("chunk tickets", chunkTickets);
  
  // Chunk Tickets does not contain the corresponding pushToken in case of success/error,
  // so I am unable to know in case of error, which pushToken should be removed from database.
  // I tried to get the receipts
  
  const ticketIds = [];
  chunkTickets?.forEach((chunk) => {
    chunk?.forEach((ticket) => {
      if ( ticket.id ) {
        ticketIds.push(ticket.id);
      }
    });
  });
  
  const receipts = await expo.getPushNotificationReceiptsAsync(ticketIds);
  console.log("receipts", receipts);
  
  // But unfortunately, receipts are also not having the "pushToken" field
  // So I don't know which pushToken is causing error and should be removed from database
  
  return receipts;
};
```

Sample Response:

```
// Sample Response
const chunkTickets = [
  [
    {
      "id": "d4574aeb-6e68-474a-9f60-7cba340a7797",
      "status": "error",
      "message": "The recipient device is not registered with FCM.",
      "details": {
        "error": "DeviceNotRegistered",
        "fault": "developer"
      }
    }
  ]
]

const receipts = {
  "d4574aeb-6e68-474a-9f60-7cba340a7797": {
    "status": "error",
    "message": "The recipient device is not registered with FCM.",
    "details": {
      "fault": "developer",
      "error": "DeviceNotRegistered",
      "sentAt": 1645233143
    },
    "__debug": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your chunks in
`const chunks = expo.chunkPushNotifications(filteredNotifications);`
have the push token in them and they directly correspond to your chunkTickets and your receipts.

I was able to do something like this

```
const tickets = [];
return Promise.all(
    chunks.map((chunk) => expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync(chunk).then((ticketChunkResponse) => {
        tickets.push(_.merge(...ticketChunkResponse, ...chunk));
        return Promise.resolve(true);
      }),
    ),
  ).then((res) => {
     checkReceipts(tickets);
  });
```

where I merged the chunks with their corresponding responses before sending them to my checkReceipt function using lodash's merge function

Comment: Hi, what is tickets here?

Comment: @kd12345 tickets is just an empty array... I have updated my answer!

Comment: Hi, thank you for getting back to me. Also, what is checkReceipts? and instead of ```_.merge``` can i use ```tickets.push({...ticketChunkResponse, ...chunk});
```?

Comment: you can try to  push without the lodash merge, but ticketChunkResponse and chunk have different shapes so they are not the same.

The checkReceipts() function is taken from the [expo-server-sdk-node](https://github.com/expo/expo-server-sdk-node) library.  I used [this bit of code](https://github.com/expo/expo-server-sdk-node#:~:text=let%20receiptIds%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B) and turned it into a seperate function to fit my use case.

Comment: Hi Anthony, can one user have multiple expo push tokens?

Comment: yes they can and probably should... Some users will use different devices and should receive a push to each device they've used.

Comment: Then when a user logs out from 1 device, i just delete that token and keep the other correct?

Comment: As far as I understand, you should store the tokens somewhere like a database in a one-to-many style relationship (one user -> many tokens).  You should send notifications to all tokens, then check the reciepts.  If a reciept comes back as 'DeviceNotRegistered' meaning the user has uninstalled your app on their device, you will then need to delete that token... see [here](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/sending-notifications/#:~:text=Push%20receipts%20may%20also%20tell%20you%20if%20a%20recipient%20device%20has%20unsubscribed%20from%20notifications)

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the party, but,

According to [Expo documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/sending-notifications/#push-tickets) "The requests above [...] will contain an array of push tickets **in the same order** in which the messages were sent [...]".

So, after sending the notifications you just merge the two arrays, preserving the order.

```
// TS example

tokens: string[] = ...
tickets: ExpoPushTicket[] = ...

const tokenAndTickets: { ticket: ExpoPushTicket; token: string }[] =
  tickets.map((ticket, index) => ({
     ticket,
     token: tokens[index],
   }));
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `chunkPushNotifications` return an array of `ExpoPushMessage[]` which have `to` prop with ExpoPushToken inside.
Please take a look https://github.com/expo/expo-server-sdk-node/blob/master/src/ExpoClient.ts#L77.

Here is my code:

```js
  // The Expo push notification service accepts batches of notifications so
  // that you don't need to send 1000 requests to send 1000 notifications. We
  // recommend you batch your notifications to reduce the number of requests
  // and to compress them (notifications with similar content will get
  // compressed).
  const chunks = expo.chunkPushNotifications(messages);
  const receipts = [];
  (async () => {
    // Send the chunks to the Expo push notification service. There are
    // different strategies you could use. A simple one is to send one chunk at a
    // time, which nicely spreads the load out over time:
    for (const chunk of chunks) {
      try {
        const ticketChunks = await expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync(chunk);

        for (let i = 0; i < ticketChunks.length; i++) {
          const ticket = ticketChunks[i];
          const chunkElement = chunk[i];

          // https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/sending-notifications/#individual-errors
          if (ticket.status === 'error') {
            if (ticket.details.error === 'DeviceNotRegistered') {
              try {
                const expoPushToken = ticket.details.expoPushToken || chunkElement.to;
                if (!expoPushToken) {
                  throw new Error('No expoPushToken in chunk or ticket');
                } else {
                  await PushTokens.destroy({where: {pushToken: expoPushToken}});
                }
              } catch (error) {
                Sentry.captureException(error, {
                  extra: {
                    ticket: JSON.stringify(ticket),
                    chunkElement: JSON.stringify(chunkElement),
                  },
                });
              }
            } else {
              console.error('Expo: error in push ticket', {ticket});
              Sentry.captureMessage(`Expo: error in push ticket (${ticket.details.error})`, {
                extra: {
                  ticket: JSON.stringify(ticket),
                  chunkElement: JSON.stringify(chunkElement),
                },
              });
            }
          } else {
            receipts.push({recipeId: ticket.id});
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error while processing ticket chunk', error);
        Sentry.captureException(error);
      }
    }

    try {
      // save PushReceipts to DB for future processing
      await PushReceipts.bulkCreate(receipts);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      Sentry.captureException(error);
    }

    console.log('sendPushNotificationToUsers log', {recepients, userPushTokens, receipts, data});
  })();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on expo documentation apparently, the token is returned in a message from the receipt.

So I wrote a little function to extract the token from the string

```js
function getPushTokenFromMessage(message) {
  const regex = /ExponentPushToken\[\w+\]/;
  const match = regex.exec(message);
  return match ? match[0] : null;
}


const data = [{
    "status": "error",
    "message": "\"ExponentPushToken[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]\" is not a registered push notification recipient",
    "details": {
      "error": "DeviceNotRegistered"
    }
  },
  {
    "status": "ok",
    "id": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
  }
]



const token = getPushTokenFromMessage(data[0].message)
console.log(token)
```

How I use it in code

```js
const receiptIdChunks =
      this.expoService.client.chunkPushNotificationReceiptIds(receiptIds);

    // Like sending notifications, there are different strategies you could use
    // to retrieve batches of receipts from the Expo service.
    for (const chunk of receiptIdChunks) {
      try {
        const receipts =
          await this.expoService.client.getPushNotificationReceiptsAsync(chunk);

        // The receipts specify whether Apple or Google successfully received the
        // notification and information about an error, if one occurred.
        for (const receiptId in receipts) {
          const { status, details } = receipts[receiptId];
          if (status === 'ok') {
            continue;
          } else if (status === 'error') {
            this.logger.error(`There was an error sending a notification:`);
            if (details && details.error) {
              if (details.error === 'DeviceNotRegistered') {
                if ((receipts[receiptId] as ExpoPushErrorReceipt).message) {
                  const { message } = receipts[
                    receiptId
                  ] as ExpoPushErrorReceipt;
                  const pushToken = this.getPushTokenFromMessage(message);
                  if (pushToken) {
                    await this.prisma.pushToken.delete({
                      where: {
                        token: pushToken,
                      },
                    });
                    this.logger.error('deleted push token', pushToken);
                  }
                }
              }
              // The error codes are listed in the Expo documentation:
              // https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/sending-notifications/#individual-errors
              // You must handle the errors appropriately.
              this.logger.error(`The error code is ${details.error}`);
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        this.logger.error(error);
      }
    }
  }
```